# Change specific column values in R

Tags: r

I have a table where there are "NA"s littered all over the place in one column in particular. I want to replace every instance of "NA" with something else -- say, the number 1.

How should I do that?

Comment: Sorry to those before the edit, but this is an R question. I'm not sure why the tags were sql and database as I didn't type them into the tags field.

Comment: Check revisions (stackoverflow.com/revisions/1858280/list). Etienne change your tags.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to check the revisions.

In any case, that's an odd revision. >_>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jonathan has the right answer for a vector, which you can apply to column a in data frame dat using:

```
> dat<-data.frame(a=c(11,2,11,NA),b=c(1,1,1,1))
> dat$a[is.na(dat$a)] <- 1
```

For completeness using Deducer's 'Recode Variables' dialog, which can do much more complicated recodings, produces the following code.

```
> library(Deducer)
> dat[c("a")] <- recode.variables(dat[c("a")] , "NA -> 1;")
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about `Deducer`.  And I think you can still use the succinct syntax `dat$a <- recode.variables(dat$a, "NA -> 1;")`.

Comment: Deducer is a great tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
x[is.na(x)] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Tablename set column='1' where column='NA'